# I am using pgAdmin 4, PostgreSQL 16, Windows 10. Whenever I try to login into pgAdmin for postgres user, I get can Connection TImeout Error

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, postgresql-9.4, pgadmin-4

I am using pgAdmin 4, PostgreSQL 16, Windows 10. Whenever I try to login into pgAdmin for postgres user, I get can Connection TImeout Error.

I tried reinstalling postgreSQL, running pgadmin 4 in adminstration, but still didn't work. I can login in command prompt but not in pgadmin 4. I get connection timeout Error.

**Please help me, as I need to learn PostgreSQL with pgAdmin.**

Some extra details:
My postgresql is in D Drive.

Here is the logs. ==>

```
pgAdmin Runtime Environment
--------------------------------------------------------
Python Path: "C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\v7\python\python.exe"
Runtime Config File: "C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin\runtime_config.json"
pgAdmin Config File: "C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\v7\web\config.py"
Webapp Path: "C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\v7\web\pgAdmin4.py"
pgAdmin Command: "C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\v7\python\python.exe -s C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\v7\web\pgAdmin4.py"
Environment: 
  - ALLUSERSPROFILE: C:\ProgramData
  - APPDATA: C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Roaming
  - CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME: \\.\pipe\crashpad_7248_MOUDUUZRFFUMRXXV
  - CHROME_RESTART: NW.js|Whoa! NW.js has crashed. Relaunch now?|LEFT_TO_RIGHT
  - CommonProgramFiles: C:\Program Files\Common Files
  - CommonProgramFiles(x86): C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
  - CommonProgramW6432: C:\Program Files\Common Files
  - COMPUTERNAME: DESKTOP-NS006PM
  - ComSpec: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
  - DriverData: C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
  - HOMEDRIVE: C:
  - HOMEPATH: \Users\manoj
  - LOCALAPPDATA: C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local
  - LOGONSERVER: \\DESKTOP-NS006PM
  - NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS: 4
  - OneDrive: C:\Users\manoj\OneDrive
  - OneDriveConsumer: C:\Users\manoj\OneDrive
  - OS: Windows_NT
  - Path: C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\v7\runtime;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;D:\PostgreSQL\bin;D:\PostgreSQL\lib;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\;C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\;C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\bin;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\lib
  - PATHEXT: .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
  - PGADMIN_INT_KEY: ba2b8d3e-ac1a-4dc5-a94f-797b38774981
  - PGADMIN_INT_PORT: 54039
  - PGADMIN_SERVER_MODE: OFF
  - PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE: AMD64
  - PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER: Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 11, GenuineIntel
  - PROCESSOR_LEVEL: 6
  - PROCESSOR_REVISION: 9e0b
  - ProgramData: C:\ProgramData
  - ProgramFiles: C:\Program Files
  - ProgramFiles(x86): C:\Program Files (x86)
  - ProgramW6432: C:\Program Files
  - PSModulePath: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
  - PUBLIC: C:\Users\Public
  - SystemDrive: C:
  - SystemRoot: C:\WINDOWS
  - TEMP: C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Temp
  - TMP: C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Temp
  - USERDOMAIN: DESKTOP-NS006PM
  - USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE: DESKTOP-NS006PM
  - USERNAME: manoj
  - USERPROFILE: C:\Users\manoj
  - windir: C:\WINDOWS
  - ZES_ENABLE_SYSMAN: 1
--------------------------------------------------------

Total spawn time to start the pgAdmin4 server: 0.027 Sec
2023-10-21 23:31:52,273: WARNING    werkzeug:   Werkzeug appears to be used in a production deployment. Consider switching to a production web server instead.

 * Serving Flask app 'pgadmin'
 * Debug mode: off

------------------------------------------
Total time taken to ping pgAdmin4 server: 8.272 Sec
------------------------------------------
Total launch time of pgAdmin4: 8.757 Sec
------------------------------------------
Application Server URL: http://127.0.0.1:54039/?key=ba2b8d3e-ac1a-4dc5-a94f-797b38774981
2023-10-21 23:32:51,601: ERROR  pgadmin:    Could not connect to server(#1) - 'PostgreSQL 16'.
Error: connection timeout expired
```

I tried reinstalling, and running pgadmin 4 as administration.